# How to make nscd generate core dump files?

Tags: coredump, setuid

nscd service crashed without a core dump file.

ulimit -c is unlimited.

Someone says that that's because nscd use "setuid" when the "server-user" is set in /etc/nscd.conf.

Then I added a "#" to delete it at the beginning of  the "server-user" line in /etc/nscd.conf then restart the service.

Now it runs as root which could be checked by "ps -ef | grep nscd".

However, the following commands still could not make nscd to generate a core dump file:
   kill -ABRT nscd-pid
or kill -s SIGSEGV nscd-pid

Who can tell me why and how? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

resolved it myself. That's because nscd is called with "daemon nscd ..." in /etc/init.d/nscd script, however the daemon function in /etc/init.d/functions modify the core dump file size to be 0, so even if issuing "ulimit -c unlimited" at the beginning of "/etc/init.d/nscd" could not make sence.

Comment: The way to do it properly is to define a variable: export DAEMON_COREFILE_LIMIT=unlimited as the daemon function does ulimit -S -c ${DAEMON_COREFILE_LIMIT:-0}"